# If not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, splice

Getting errors in my code and trying to nail it down to the specific part and cannot understand the behaviour of this if block

```
 if (logged_in_user_object.useruid === cookie_value){
            //this.state.future_users.splice(logged_in_user_object, 1);
            console.log('hello');
          }
```

this.state.future_users is length of 4.
`logged_in_user_object.useruid` is unique everytime.
`cookie_value` is unique.
I have consoled logged before and `logged_in_user_object.useruid` AND `cookie_value` are the same. 
it is not splicing the correct one and I have no idea why not

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? The code you posted does not make a reference to `i`, so the `if` statement will do exactly the same thing every time.

Comment: It shouldn't be logging once. You have 4 users, so you're looping through them. logged_in_user_object.useruid and cookie_value don't change, so it doesn't matter which iteration of the loop you're on. They'll still be the same, so the condition always passes, so 'hello' always gets logged.

Comment: Can you post the dataset being run through it?  To get it, you could console log `JSON.stringify(this.state.future_users)` and paste it in here (or format it back properly first).

Comment: Ignore what I wrote before-- listen to @Pointy -- he's pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @Pointy that helped somewhat, cheers. but now I have got rid of the for loop and am splicing the user (put the commented out code back in) and it is not splicing the correct one. anything from this code you can see?

Comment: Please adjust your title and tags if you're not asking about a loop

Comment: You might want to have a look at [the docs for `splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) again. It does take an index and a number (and potentially some new elements), but never an object as its first argument? What do you expect this call to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, you are never using i anywhere; so the condition in the if statement is the same every time?